# Nylon gears for 0.4Nm torque

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears

I see that POM gears are often not preferred in high torque settings - but how about 0.4Nm? Is that amount of torque too much for module 1 POM bevel gears? Say they are 16-tooth.

Is 0.4Nm considered moderately high torque?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

module 1 16T bevel POM (also called acetal or Delrin) gears are rated at 0.2Nm at http://www.huco.com/products.asp?p=true&cat=285

The webpage also list larger module gears torque ratings.

0.4 Nm is considered low torque in industrial machinery, but could be considered high torque in other fields.